# Flickering while dragging a file over drop zone

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dropzone

I'm trying to do the effect where the window shows a drop zone that fills the window only when you drag a file over it and disappear when you cancel the drag or drop the file.

Almost all examples of react-dropzone demonstrate a drop zone that is always visible which is not what I want.

Take a look on this CodeSandbox to understand the problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-buck-2fwm6?file=/src/App.js

Or check the code here:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import { Box, makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme =>
  createStyles({
    dropZone: {
      flex: 1,
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      // padding: "20px",
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderRadius: 2,
      borderColor: "#eeeeee",
      borderStyle: "dashed",
      backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
      color: "#bdbdbd",
      outline: "none",
      transition: "border .24s ease-in-out",
      position: "absolute",
      width: "calc(100% - 4px)",
      height: "calc(100% - 4px)",
      zIndex: 10
    }
  })
);
const useDropzoneInternal = () => {
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, open } = useDropzone({
    noClick: true
  });
  const inputProps = getInputProps();
  const { ref, ...rootProps } = getRootProps();
  return { rootProps, inputProps, ref, open, isDragActive };
};

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let { rootProps, isDragActive, inputProps } = useDropzoneInternal();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box
        {...rootProps}
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        flexGrow={1}
        position="relative"
      >
        {isDragActive && (
          <Box className={classes.dropZone}>
            <Box>
              <input {...inputProps} />
              {<p>Drop the files here ...</p>}
            </Box>
          </Box>
        )}
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Drag a file here!</h2>
        <h2>Unfortunately, the drop zone appears and disappears</h2>
        <h2>Because the gray area covers the parent</h2>
        <h2>And hijack the onDragEvent</h2>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see I'm showing the dropzone when **isDragActive** is **true**, but it immediately flips back to **false** because the newly shown area covers the parent div (and probably cancels the drag event).

How can I get around this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was missing and it was silly as I expected, you need to pass the `ref` to the parent element that decides the boundaries of the drag event.

```
  let { ref, rootProps, isDragActive, inputProps } = useDropzoneInternal();

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={ref}>
```

or if you want to stick to Material UI component:

```
<div className="App">
  <RootRef rootRef={ref}>
    <Box
      {...rootProps}
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
```

I was under the impressions that it is not required, and it will be assigned if you destruct the {...rootProps} on the parent div.